# What type of Bacteria?

Tags: species-identification, bacteriology

I did some tests to a bacteria colony and I observed the following:

First of all let's start from the shape and after that we move on to the chemical tests that I did to them:

- **Form**: *Circular*
- **Colour**: *Yellow-to-white* (something like pale yellow)
- **Margin**: *Entire*
- **Elevation**: *Flat*

Chemical results:

- **Gram**: Negative
- **Catalase**: Positive
- **Oxidase**: Positive

After some research to the databases, I figured out that it might be:

If it belongs to the family of **Pseudomonas**:

- *Chryseomonas luteola* **OR** *Pseudomonas luteola group Ve-1* with a chance of 48.21%
- *Flavimonas oryzihabitans group Ve-2* with a chance of 48.21%
- *Xanthomonas maltophilia* **OR** *Pseudomonas-like spp*, with a extremely low possibility of 1.34%.

**So, my question has 3 parts:**

- Can someone please tell me if my hypothesis is right?
- And if it is possible which bacteria from the above is the correct?
- If you manage to find the correct type of bacteria can someone tell me the ideal enviroment to study them better? (agar plates, temperature, time needed, etc.) Thank you for all the efforts made!

**Important notice**: I have used a blood agar plate with a concentration of 5–10%. It contains as far I know, mammalian blood maybe from sheep or horse. I forgot to check the temperature, but I don't think that it is very important.

Comment: Sounds a bit like homework/course work to me...

I don't have an answer for you immediately, but if your observation that the cells are circular (coccoid) is correct, it can't be *Xantho/Pseudomonas.* If the results are to be trusted, that they are G- cocci, there aren't very many options, just *Veillionella, Moraxella and Neisseria*, pretty much http://rx.osumc.edu/asp2/microbiology/gramNegOrganisms.pdf.

Try Bergey's Manual of Systematic Bacteriology (I can't find an online copy though).

Your use of media and temperature can be **very** important. How was it incubated? Anaerobically?

Comment: @JoeHealey 30 degrees, aerobically. I will check now the Systematic Bacteriology, thanks for that guide!

Comment: Aerobically would rule out *Veillonella*, but I haven't checked whether *Moraxella/Neisseria* are Catalase/Oxidase positive or capable of growing on blood agar.

Comment: Well I will let you do your research.. When done post the results to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolidating my comments, and taking all the results at face value (though microbiology can be very tricky), the most likely candidates are *Moraxella*, or *Neisseria spp*.

Gram negative cocci (spherical cells) rules out a large number of possibilities, leaving just the above 2 and *Veillonella* as candidates.

[image]

The OP said that the culturing was done under aerobic conditions at 30˚C. *Veillonella* is an obligate anaerobe, and so wouldn't survive this. Both *Moraxella* and *Neisseria* are happiest at 37˚C but would no doubt grow at 30. Both are cultivable on blood agar. *Neisseria* is best cultured in a 5% CO2 atmosphere, so is probably somewhat less likely. Both appear as pale-whitish colonies on plates. The OP's observation of yellowish colouring could be artifactual of the plate colouring, I'm not 100% sure.

Both are positive for oxidase and catalase.

## Neisseria on blood agar:

[image]

## Moraxella on blood agar:

[image]

#### One final comment: both of these are pathogens, so continue with all due caution.

*Moraxella*, in particular, is a respiratory pathogen, so I would advise working in a biosafety cabinet. I'll assume you already have the relevant paperwork/permission to be handling > BSL1 organisms...

Comment: Lovely answer, covers me 100%. And of course I have permission to work on pathogens... besides thats my future job! Pathologist....(still studing and experimenting but ok)

Comment: Great, that's good - thought I'd check. If it was a school experiment or something, they may not have had the relevant safety frameworks, so thought it best!

Comment: University experiment in special labs... and tutors-personnel that are always watching us.